# ios - error while uploading application at device anywhere studio

Tags: ios, testing

I'm trying to upload an iphone application to device anywhere studio.

But when I'm clicking on the "Data cable" button to deliver my application, it gives me this error:

Unable to upload application(error code:ensemble_error_unknown_error).

But I could run andriod application successfully. Why it should be happen only in iphone.? Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that error message is not very specific you should contact the Device Anywhere support team for advise.

Here's a link with the description of the upload process and a contact for support.
http://deviceanywhere.typepad.com/deviceanywhere/2010/03/uploading-applications-to-an-iphone.html

Good luck.